# How to extract something occuring after some common paths?

Tags: awk, sed, grep

I want to filter out anything that occurs after some common paths. Example, Print out the next word that occurs every pytests/ OR after src/

for "src/cs-test/test_bugcheck_0001.py"
awk -F"/" '{print $2}' works

for "metadata/pytests/ipa-cert.yaml"
awk -F"/pytest/" '{print $2}' | awk -F"." '{print $1}' works

But I want to have these in one awk statement.

```
metadata/pytests/ipa-cert.yaml
src/cs-test/test_bugcheck_0001.py
```

Expected result:

```
ipa-cert
cs-test
```

Comment: Try `awk '{ print gensub(/^(.*\/pytests\/|^[^/]+\/)([^/.]+).*/, "\\2", 1) }' file`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suggest  using

```
sed -E 's,^(.*/pytests/|[^/]+/)([^/.]+).*,\2,' file > newfile
```

See the [online `sed` demo](https://ideone.com/2WL7V1) and the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/KQDei8/1) (not proof).

**POSIX ERE pattern details**

- `^` - start of line
- `(.*/pytests/|[^/]+/)` - Group 1: either of the two alternatives:

  - `.*/pytests/` - any 0+ chars as many as possible and then `/pytests/` string
  - `|` - or
  - `[^/]+/` - a negated bracket expression matching 1+ chars other than `/` and then a `/`
- `([^/.]+)` - Group 2: a negated bracket expression matching 1 or more chars other than `/` and `.`
- `.*` - any 0 or more chars up to the line end.

The `,` chars are used as delimiters in the sed command so as not to overescape the pattern that has many `/` chars.

Answer (score 1):

Simple substitutions on individual strings is what sed is designed to do. With GNU or OSX/BSD sed for `-E`:

```
$ sed -E 's:(^|.*/)(pytests|src)/([^/.]+).*:\3:' file
ipa-cert
cs-test
```

or if you really want to use awk for some reason then with GNU awk for gensub():

```
$ awk '{print gensub(/(^|.*\/)(pytests|src)\/([^/.]+).*/,"\\3",1)}' file
ipa-cert
cs-test
```

and with any awk:

```
$ awk 'match($0,/(^|.*\/)(pytests|src)\/[^/.]+/){$0=substr($0,1,RLENGTH); sub(/.*\//,"")} 1' file
ipa-cert
cs-test
```